# Why my logical operator is not working properly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am checking a certain question that if the answer of question1 and question are 1 and 2 or the answer of question3 is 3 then run a specific program that but the && doesn't seem to work properly. As when I write 1 in question1 then the condition will ran even though the value of question2 is not equal to 2.

```
function getRandom() {
        let text="Answer"
        const obj = {
          question1: prompt('How many Stars are there in our solar system?', text),
          question2: prompt('How many Moon does Mars have?', text),
          question3: prompt('How many Moons do we have?', text),
        };
        if (((obj.question1==1) && (obj.question2==2)) || (obj.question3==3)){
        var oldVal = 'Name';
        var name = prompt("Write your name:", oldVal)
        if (name === "") { }
        else if (name == oldVal) { }
        else if (name) {
          alert("Congrats " + name + "!!! You just won " + value + "$")
        }
        else {
          alert("You just missed the golden chance to become a billionaire")
        }
      }
      else{
        alert("Sorry")
      }}
```

Comment: Can i ask for additional details? Like your code does what you said, for which combinations of answers it works in a wrong way? Show the expected behavior. Something like Table of Function, i.e. [1,2,3] => true, [1,3,3] => true, [1,1,0] => false and etc. Not all of them but only the necessary ones for your case.

Comment: this video is helpful in understanding logical operators, and may help you as well:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHpLGco_jSk&list=PLaZSdijfCCJDm33pC1WX56jTW1r9Ln1EG&index=20